# Cyrillic text doesn't show up in Reader's bookmarks or Evince outline

Tags: cyrillic

I'm trying to use `hyperref` to make Content clickable. And it mostly works but for UI in viewers.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents
  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Chappy}
  \section{Text}
  \section{Український текст}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` and remove `T1` from the font encodings (I don't know why it affects bookmarks).

Comment: @SergeiGolovan both should not be necessary in a current tex system.   unicode is the default in hyperref now anyway. The example works fine for me as it is.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, though I confirm that it doesn't work in TeXLive 2019 (MS Windows) and a version of TeXLive 2020 which comes with Debian 11.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan yes in older systems you need the unicode option, but T1 shouldn't matter (and it doesn't matter for me).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right, rechecked again. It looks like I've stumbled on a latexmk bug. It didn't rerun pdflatex enough times to switch from the older build without `unicode` to the newer build with `unicode`. `T1` really doesn't matter after all. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you may want to add your explanation as an answer. I will accept it.